# jbd2 keeps writing to disk. Is that normal/healthy?

Tags: kernel

jbd2 keeps accessing the disk every few seconds for the last hour.  Is that supposed to happen?  I have this issue frequently after unsuspending my laptop.  It drains my battery.  If I reboot it goes away.  Any thoughts?